# Event loop is closed while runing Celery tasks

Tags: python, django, celery

I got the following RuntimeError when I run Celery worker, I'm new to Celery and I don't understand the source of this bug and why the task exception is not retrieved. My Celery tasks run but if I click on any trigger, the error shows up frequently and I ended up with another opertationalError that said:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: database is locked
```

```
[2022-10-25 13:22:58,428: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-2] Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-77' coro=<Connection.disconnect() done, defined at /home/.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/asyncio/connection.py:819> exception=RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/asyncio/connection.py", line 828, in disconnect
    self._writer.close()  # type: ignore[union-attr]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/streams.py", line 353, in close
    return self._transport.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 692, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 719, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 508, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
```